# Conversion in derived class inaccessible if base class is protected

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++14, wxwidgets

**Update:**
[This was a bug in wxWidgets](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/17623). This has been fixed in wxWidgets 3.1.1, if you're using a C++11 compatible compiler.

---

I'm trying to dynamically bind an event handler to an event in wxWidgets. Unfortunately if the derived class is protected it doesn't seem to work.

Minimal example:

```
// Test.h
class Test : protected wxFrame
{
public:
    Test();

private:
    void sizing(wxSizeEvent& event);
};

// Test.cpp
Test::Test()
{
    Bind(wxEVT_SIZING, &Test::sizing, this);
}

void Test::sizing(wxSizeEvent& event)
{
}
```

That unfortunately doesn't seem to work and nets the following error on Visual Studio 2015 Update 3:

```
wxWidgets\include\wx/meta/convertible.h(31): error C2243: 'type cast': conversion from 'Test *' to 'wxEvtHandler *' exists, but is inaccessible
  wxWidgets\include\wx/event.h(335): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'wxConvertibleTo<Class,wxEvtHandler>' being compiled
          with
          [
              Class=Test
          ]
  wxWidgets\include\wx/event.h(3568): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'wxEventFunctorMethod<EventTag,Test,EventArg,EventHandler>' being compiled
          with
          [
              EventTag=wxEventTypeTag<wxSizeEvent>,
              EventArg=wxSizeEvent,
              EventHandler=Test
          ]
  Test.cpp(78): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void wxEvtHandler::Bind<wxEventTypeTag<wxSizeEvent>,Test,wxSizeEvent,Test>(const EventTag &,void (__cdecl Test::* )(EventArg &),EventHandler *,int,int,wxObject *)' being compiled
          with
          [
              EventTag=wxEventTypeTag<wxSizeEvent>,
              EventArg=wxSizeEvent,
              EventHandler=Test
          ]
```

Changing the inheritance to public makes it work:

```
class Test : public wxFrame
```

1. Why is the conversion inaccessible when the inheritance is protected?
2. I do not wish to expose wxFrame to the world, but only the classes that derive the Test class. How can I do this while still being able to dynamically bind the event handler?

Comment: Why do you expect protected inheritance to work for you? It won't. OO frameworks in C++ rely on public inheritance.

Comment: @Barry Bind is a method that binds the given method to be called whenever the given event (in this case SIZING) is executed. See http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html#overview_events_bind for more information.

Comment: @n.m. I'm not sure what you mean, but I don't see a reason for why changing inheritance to protected would cause the conversion to become inaccessible.

Comment: You could friend `Bind`, that would fix it

Comment: The error message should contain the line number and possibly the function where the failure occurs. Which function is that?

Comment: @David Yes, right until the moment the problematic part moves to std::bind or boost::bind or wx::detail::internal::do_not_reference::bind.

Comment: I don't see anything in the docs that requires any inheritance from `wxFrame` - seems like it takes any handler.

Comment: @Barry In this case Test is a custom frame class. Bind() in this case is inherited down the line and is used to bind a custom event handler to the frame. I have added the full compiler output to the question.

Comment: Hmm perhaps it's a bug of wx, AFAICT Bind should not require any particular inheritance.

Comment: @tambre, more importantly - why do you need "protected inheritance"? What purpose does it serve? From the OOP perspective, since you are doing GUI development - there is nothing you gain.

Comment: @Igor In my case it is actually a wrapper for a rendering window/surface that will be created/used by any part of the code that will perform rendering (the class itself is inherited by OGLFrame, VulkanFrame, DXFrame, etc). And since the application is multi-platform there are also platforms where wxWidgets is unusable and thus exists the given class and general methods for interacting with the surface (whatever it may be).  I'd like the platform-specific functions (ie. wxWidgets or Android, etc) to not be visible to the code that uses the class and only the actualy wrapper functions.

Comment: @tambre, that's ok. you can still use public inheritance. I would check documentatiojn on how to start a new port. that will give you an idea on how to make it work

Comment: If client code can't count on the fact that your class is a subclass of wxWidget, then why does it inherit at all?  Test should `has-a` wxWidget, not `is-a`.  Just make the wxWidget an (apparently optional) member of your class.

Comment: @Igor I think I'll likely be using the native GUI widgets myself on Android, as the current design would never fit for Android.

Comment: @Peter That's a good point, thanks for the advice, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work around this using the following:

```
Bind(wxEVT_SIZING, std::bind(&Test::sizing, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Minimal sample that compiles:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <functional>
using namespace std::placeholders;

class Test : protected wxFrame
{
public:
    Test();

private:
    void sizing(wxSizeEvent& event);
};
Test::Test()
{
    Bind(wxEVT_SIZING, std::bind(&Test::sizing, this, _1));
}

void Test::sizing(wxSizeEvent& event)
{
}

class MyApp: public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};
class MyFrame: public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
private:
};
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame( "", wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(450, 340) );
    frame->Show( true );
    return true;
}

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size) : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size)
{
    Test* test = new Test();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This indeed looks like a defect in wxWidgets event handling code because the error comes from the check done by `wxConvertibleTo` to determine whether `Test` derives from `wxEvtHandler` or not (and here it doesn't do it publicly).

The simplest fix I can recommend is to use a temporary lambda, which bypasses this check, e.g. this works (provided you use C++11, of course):

```
#include <wx/frame.h>

class Test : protected wxFrame {
public:
    Test() { Bind(wxEVT_SIZING, [=](wxSizeEvent& e) { sizing(e); }); }

private:
    void sizing(wxSizeEvent&) { }
};
```